# Using reactPrime library in DataView components how update dynamic values (react hook)?

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, dataview

how I can update price value when update quantity value automatically ??

page design
[interface ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjySj.png)

print values on the console:
[print values on the console:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8L1I.png)

This sentence needs to be modified
{quantity[initQ] == 1 ? data.price : initP[initQ]}

i use setState to save multiple values

```
export default function Contaner({ setPressed, getPressed }) {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [layout, setLayout] = useState('list');
  let initQ = 1;
  const [initP,setInitP] = useState({ [initQ]: 1 }) ;
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState({ [initQ]: 1 });

  function checkQuantity(e, data) {
       if (e.value <= data.quantity) {
        initQ = data.name;
        setQuantity({ ...quantity, [data.name]:  e.value});
        setInitP( { ...quantity, [data.name]:  data.price * e.value});
        console.log(initP  );
        setCart(current => [...current, data.name]);

        }
        else {

           showError();
              }

  }


const renderListItem = (data) => {

   return (
            <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
            <button className="button_color" onClick={() => removeItem(data)}>
            <i className="pi pi-trash"></i>
            </button>
            <h6>{quantity[initQ] == 1 ? data.price : initP[initQ] }</h6>
            <InputNumber id="stacked" showButtons min={1} value={quantity[initQ]}
               onValueChange={(e) => checkQuantity(e, data)} />
            <InputText disabled={true} value={"₪  " + data.price} />
            <h6>{data.name}</h6>
            </div>

      );
     }


  const itemTemplate = (product, layout) => {

     if (!product) {

      return <></>;
      }

     if (layout === 'list') {
        return renderListItem(product);
      }

    }

 return(

    <DataView value={products} layout={layout} itemTemplate={itemTemplate} rows={1} />

       );

 }
```